# How can I avoid C++ creating extra copies of a given class instance?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a `Child` class that holds references to externally managed memory (in this particular case, Vulkan objects that are created/deleted via Vulkan calls, and not through the standard C++ memory management lifecycle). For the purposes of reproduction, this is exemplified with a manual allocation of memory in the example below. I want to still rely on RAII to handle my C++ objects and release the externally allocated memory on the destructor of `Child`. In my actual code are multiple instances of `Child` in a `Parent` class, so I am also including this here for completion. Here's an MRE:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class Child {
    public:
        Child(void * memoryRegion): mMemoryRegion(memoryRegion){}
        ~Child(){
            std::cout << "Destroying" << std::endl;
            free(mMemoryRegion);
        }
        Child(const Child&) = delete;
        Child(Child&&) = default;
        Child& operator=(const Child&) = delete;
        Child& operator=(Child&&) = default;

    private:
        void * mMemoryRegion;
};

Child createChild(){
    void * memory = malloc(100);
    return Child(memory);
}


class Parent {
    public:
        Parent (Child &c1) : child1(std::move(c1)){}
    private:
        Child child1;
};

std::unique_ptr<Parent> createParent(){
    Child c1 = createChild();
    return std::make_unique<Parent>(c1);
}

int main(){
    auto parent = createParent();
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I have tried to disable the copy constructors, and used `std::move` semantics, but this still causes a crash:

```
Destroying
Destroying
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
[1]    3568506 IOT instruction  ./main
```

I am sure this is a silly mistake on my move semantics, but I have not been able to figure it out. What would be the right way to do this? I could try with `std::unique_ptr`, which I am pretty sure would fix the issue, but I am still curious to see if this can be fixed without it.

Comment: the problem is that when `createParent` function finishes, the child `c1` is destructed and thus freeing memory. Then a second time, when `parent` is destroyed in main.

Comment: You need to *implement* move semantics, rather than deleting them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
        ~Child(){
            std::cout << "Destroying" << std::endl;
            free(mMemoryRegion);
        }
```

If this object is still moved from, at some point, it's destructor ***still*** executes.

So, when this object gets moved from, before all and said and done, two objects will be destroyed and there are going to be two destructors both trying to `free` the same pointer. Good bye.

Move semantics ***do not*** change the core C++ fundamental principle: every object that gets constructed will get destroyed (in a well-formed C++ program, various edge cases involving `exit()`/`abort()` are immaterial for the purpose of this discussion).

A move is just an "efficient" copy. That's all. You cannot "avoid" creating "extra copies" when an object is moved to a new instance of a class. C++ does not work this way. You now have a new object. The moved from object still exists. Nothing happened to it. Its destructor will still execute, at some point.

You must always implement your classes accordingly. For example:

You cannot use the default move constructor here. Your move constructor must copy the moved-from object's pointer, like the default constructor does, but then set the moved-from object's pointer to `nullptr`.

Your move assignment operator must `free` the moved-to object's existing pointer, if its not null, copy the moved-from object's pointer, and then set it to `nullptr`.

Your destructor should be adjusted to `free` only a non-`nullptr` pointer, pedantically.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I suppose then the only way to achieve this is through the usage of pointers (via unique_ptr to handle them safely), right?

Comment: @martinarroyo No. You can trivially achieve your goal by implementing the move constructor as explained in this answer.

Comment: Yes, replacing the plain pointer with `std::unique_ptr` should be sufficient. It'll give you the proper move semantics, which will include copy constructor deletion, since `unique_ptr` is not copyable, classes with a `unique_ptr` as a member won't be copyable, either.

Comment: Freeing a ``nullptr`` is safe because no action occurs in such case

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Now it is a bit clearer to me what is happening in the background

Answer (score 3):

```
Child(Child&&) = default;
Child& operator=(Child&&) = default;
```

This is **not** what you want if your class directly manages resources.

The defaulted move constructor and move assignment operator will not zero out anything in the source object. Consequently, the moved-from object will still point to a resource that now belongs to some other object.

You want to either write your move constructor and move assignment operator the long way, zeroing out the moved-from pointers, or (better still) use a standard class that manages a resource, such as `std::unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Child c1 = createChild();
return std::make_unique<Parent>(c1);
```

Child `c1` **will** be destroyed at the end of this scope.

This is toxic:

```
Parent (Child &c1) : child1(std::move(c1)){}
```

if you are going to move from a reference, take an rvalue reference:

```
Parent (Child&&c1) : child1(std::move(c1)){}
```

that in turn will make the first bit of code I posted not compile.  To fix it we do:

```
Child c1 = createChild();
return std::make_unique<Parent>(std::move(c1));
```

... and we still get the crash.  But at least we don't have `Parent` silently and without warning `std::move`ing the state of a Child object.

Your next problem is here:

```
    ~Child(){
        std::cout << "Destroying" << std::endl;
        free(mMemoryRegion);
    }
    Child(const Child&) = delete;
    Child(Child&&) = default;
    Child& operator=(const Child&) = delete;
    Child& operator=(Child&&) = default;
```

this is a rule-of-5 violation.  Your destructor is non-trivial - that means the default move and copy constructor and assignment **are not going to be correct**.

You have `=default`'d your move constructor and move assignment.  Either implement them, or `=delete` them.

If you delete them, then the `Parent` constructor that `std::move`'s will fail.  This isn't completely impossible to fix -- the `Parent` constructor could take `Child` *constructor arguments* and directly construct its child -- but might not be what you want.

Option 2 is to fix `Child(Child&&)` and `~Child`.

One of the rules of C++ is that compile time errors are your friend.  Getting errors for incorrect code is a boon, because it means that the compiler is detecting your mistakes!  Often the easiest way to silence the error is *incorrect*, as you have demonstrated.

### Option 1:

```
    ~Child(){
        std::cout << "Destroying" << std::endl;
        free(mMemoryRegion);
    }
    Child(const Child&) = delete;
    Child(Child&&) = delete;
    Child& operator=(const Child&) = delete;
    Child& operator=(Child&&) = delete;
```

this class is sessile!  It can only be constructed in place.

This breaks:

```
std::unique_ptr<Parent> createParent(){
  Child c1 = createChild();
  return std::make_unique<Parent>(c1);
}
```

we fix it this way:

```
std::unique_ptr<Parent> createParent(){
  return std::make_unique<Parent>([]{
    return createChild();
  });
}
```

we pass a *child creator* to `Parent` instead of an actual child.

```
class Parent {
  public:
    template<class Creator> requires std::invoke_result_t<Creator, Child>
    Parent (Creator creator) : child1(creator()){}
  private:
    Child child1;
};
```

and we construct `child1` *in-place* using a passed-in creation function and the magic of guaranteed elision/RVO.

This technique required [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) for a few steps.

### Option 2:

we make `Child` move-friendly.

```
~Child(){
  if (mMemoryRegion)
    free(mMemoryRegion);
}
Child(const Child& o) = delete
Child& operator=(const Child&) = delete;

Child(Child&&):mMemoryRegion(o.mMemoryRegion) { o.mMemoryRegion=nullptr; }
Child& operator=(Child&& o)& = delete; // really, move-assignment is passe
```

in this case, some `Child` can have a null `mMemoryRegion` if moved-from.

Then we fix parent ctor:

```
Parent(Child&& c1):child1(std::move(c1)) {}
```

and the factory function:

```
Child c1 = createChild();
return std::make_unique<Parent>(std::move(c1));
```

and your code works.

...

Which of these two options you prefer is really up to you.  Prior to [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20), for Option 1 I'd use emplace logic:

```
template<class...Ts> /* requires std::constructible_from<Child, Ts&&...>
Parent( Ts&&... ts ):child1(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...)) {}
```

which passes in the arguments for the child to the parent to be constructed; if you have more than one child, you can take a tuple per child or something.

The factory function solution is cleaner in my opinion than proxied emplaces.

Answer (score 0):

Even if moved, the constructor of the object moved from is getting called. To make sure the constructor is only called once you could use `std::unique_ptr`. [see demo](https://godbolt.org/z/f557TaMbx). Like this you can keep your code structure, though it might be better to use
`std::unique_ptr` with a custom deleter.

Comment: There’s absolutely no need for (smart) pointers here (to clarify: implementing `Child` in terms of a `std::unique_ptr` to handle the Vulcan resource internally is potentially a good idea; but the user of these classes should not have to deal with pointers; value semantics are fine here).